# Defining public Constants file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a single file to contain all Constants.

Here is my constants.js module:

```
module.exports.TRIP_STATUS = Object.freeze({   
  TRIP_STAUTS_INITIATED         : 1000,
  TRIP_STAUTS_PENDING_PRE_INSP  : 1001,
  TRIP_STAUTS_ACTIVE            : 1002,
  TRIP_STAUTS_PENDING_POST_INSP : 1003,
  TRIP_STAUTS_DONE              : 1004,
  TRIP_STAUTS_UNKNOWN           : 1005
});
```

In my main index.js i am trying to do something like

```
var Constants = require('constants');
console.log(Constants.TRIP_STAUTS_INITIATED);
```

However its not reading the enum.

What is wrong my code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You write constants object into TRIP_STATUS object. So, you can get them with the next way:

```
console.log(Constants.TRIP_STATUS.TRIP_STAUTS_INITIATED);
```

Or, you can do with the next way:

```
module.exports = {
    TRIP_STAUTS_INITIATED         : 1000,
    ...
}
```

And get constants as you want:

```
console.log(Constants.TRIP_STAUTS_INITIATED);
```

Comment: console.log(Constants.TRIP_STATUS.TRIP_STAUTS_INITIATED); is not working either

Answer (score 5):

`constants` is a native module of Node.js like `fs`, `http`, so `require("constants")` will only output native constants. If you want to import your local constant.js, you should `require("./constants")`(ABSOLUTE PATH NOT RELATIVE ONE).

Answer (score 0):

to give some more detail:

you are importing the entire exports object

`var Constants = require('constants')`

what you need to do is import only the section you are trying to reference as the constants object

`var Constants = require('constants'). TRIP_STATUS;`

this is because of the way you are exporting it

`module.exports.TRIP_STATUS = Object.freeze`

you are exporting your constants object under the property TRIP_STATUS

or you can reference it without changing your import/export by referencing the object property

`Constants.TRIP_STAUTS.` + desired constant

Comment: Constants.TRIP_STATUS.TRIP_STAUTS_INITIATED i want to do this, what should i do above?

Answer (score 0):

Modern syntaxis:

**strings.js**

```
export default {
    errorMsg1 : '.................',
    errorMsg2 : '.................'
}
```

**other.js**

```
import strings from '../../util/strings'

console.log(errorMsg1)
```